# sort python dictionary on values where values is a tuple

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

this is my dictionary:

```
    x = {'1':('hi','10','0.1','A'),
         '2':('bye','20','0.3','B')}
```

I want to sort on the second item of the second tuple and i tried this.

```
sorted_x =
sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

However it is not sorting.

I know the `1` in `key = operator.itemgetter(1)` means sort on second tuple and not second item in tuple. so how do i sort on second item in second tuple? It is the column with value `'20'` and `'10'`.

output i want:

```
sorted_x =
[('2',('bye','20','0.3','B')),
 ('1',('hi','10','0.1','A'))]
```

Comment: That's not a Python dictionary, it's a list of tuples.  Dictionary (dict) is a very specific term in Python, and is a builtin data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want to do is make a function using `lambda`.

This should work `sorted(x.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][1], reverse=True)`. The idea is to make a function that returns the second item of the second item of a tuple `t`.

Comment: I have changed my variable name to be `x` like in your edits. Otherwise, I don't see any required changes.

Comment: So why didnt the `key = operator.itemgetter(1)` work when x is a dictionary or is there a way to do it like `key = operator.itemgetter(1)[1]`?

Comment: What you provide for `key` must be callable. `itemgetter` creates a callable object. The problem is that this callable object is not iterable (so no `itemgetter(1)[1]`). We also cannot easily extend it to call itself again. Hence lambda is the easiest way to make a function that gets the second item of the second item of a list.